# Sorting and Displaying data in sectioned table view using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ipad, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am having database in the following manner.
ProductionHouse <----> Movies <----> MovieType

Each ProductionHouse has multiple movies associated with it. I am using NSFetchedResultsController to populate the sectioned table view. Every time i select a production house the Movies table displays all the movies irrespective of the production house.

For eg: "A" production house has 3 movies and in all there are 10 movies in the "Movies" entity. On selection of the production house "A" the movies table displays all the 10 movies.

How do i put a check on this and display movies related to the production house selected? Any kind of help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this sample it will helpful https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405